# linux x64 addition program

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, nasm

I am making an addition program using x64 assembly, but it does not display a value when run (compiled with nasm, elf64).

```
section .text
global _start

_start:
mov rax, 0
add rax, [num1B]
add rax, [num2B]
mov [result], rax
mov rsi, [result]
;mov    rdx, 8  
mov rax, 4
mov rdi, 1
int 80h

mov rax, 1
mov rdi, 0
int 080h


section .data

num1B: dq 0Ah
num2B: dq 0Ah
result: dq 00h
```

Does anyone know why this is not displaying anything

Comment: Yeah, there's no text where you've pointed `rsi`.

Comment: You can't use int80h in 64-bit assembly. Instead use syscalls. See http://cs.lmu.edu/~ray/notes/x86assembly/ for some examples. You should also convert your quadword into human readable form (ie. ASCII) before calling write(2).

Comment: How would I convert it to ASCII? I also changed the line:   MOV RSI, [result] to MOV RSI, result.

Answer (score 0):

1.later use printf instead of interrupts, much better, 
2.why put values of numB1 and numB2 instead of their location.
Use: mov rax, numB1.
3.in 64bit nasm assembly you use the:
`rdi, rsi, rbx, rcx,...` Registers for putting in values for interrupts.
For example:

```
mov rdi, 01
mov rsi, 00
syscall
```

1. DON't USE `int0x80`!, for more-portability use `syscall` and besides `int 0x80` didn't work on my system.

Hope it helps, Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I will use syscall, but the program still doesn't display a result.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to print 'result' to stdout and you are using the 32-bit
system call values.

In 64-bit linux the system call for write is 1 and you would write to stdout like this... att&t syntax:
first strip values in %rax and push them byte by byte on stack, say %rax
holds the value 0x7ffffff8:

```
mov $0xa, %rbx        # divisor

nibble:
xor %rdx, %rdx        # will hold bytes values you need
div %rbx, %rax
push %rdx             # save remainder
inc  %r8              # count digit, write seems to trash %rcx
cmp  $0,  %rax        # done?
jne  nibble           # no, get another digit

#set up for write to stdout

mov $1, %rax          # sys_call for write
mov $1, %rdi          # write to stdout
mov $result, %rsi     # addr. of value to print

# now get values from stack, make ascii and write to stdout

decimal:
pop %rdx              # get digit off stack
add $0x30, %dl        # make ascii printable
movb %dl, result      # load addr. with value
mov $1, %rdx          # print 1 byte
syscall

dec %r8
jnz decimal           # go till %r8 is zero
```

You just need to set up a 1 byte data holder for digits,either in data section:

```
.section .data
    result:
    .byte 0             # reserves 1 byte and inits to 0
```

or  the uninitialized data area:

```
.section .bss
    .lcomm result, 1    # reserves 1 byte
```

I'm sure there are better ways to do this, should give you some ideas though.

Get a 64-bit system call list, they have changed quite a lot from the 32-bit calls.